# Future builder gives failed assertion error

Tags: flutter

I am populating my list through an API call and sending data to future builder..it is retrieving the data from API call properly and returning it but the app is crashing and giving error while building the Future Builder:

My code:

```
  createNewTaskView(BuildContext context, List<String> societies){
      return Container(         
                DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                  child: DropdownButton<String>(
                    value: _selectedSociety,
                    onChanged: (String newValue) {
                      setState(() {
                        _selectedSociety = newValue;
                      });
                    },
                    items: societies.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                      return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                        value: value,
                        child:  Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 0.0, right: 0.0),
                          child: Text(value),
                        ),
                      );
                    })
                        .toList(),
                  ),),                            
            ),
          ));

    }


    return Scaffold(

      body: FutureBuilder(
          future: getAllData,
          initialData: [],
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData || snapshot.data.isEmpty) return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(valueColor: new AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.red),));
            else {
              return createNewTaskView(context, snapshot.data);
            }
          }),
    );
```

Error:

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (10866): The following assertion was thrown building FutureBuilder<List<dynamic>>(dirty, state:
I/flutter (10866): _FutureBuilderState<List<dynamic>>#29af2):
I/flutter (10866): 'package:flutter/src/material/dropdown.dart': Failed assertion: line 560 pos 15: 'items == null ||
I/flutter (10866): items.isEmpty || value == null || items.where((DropdownMenuItem<T> item) => item.value ==
I/flutter (10866): value).length == 1': is not true.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is in this condition:

```
    if (!snapshot.hasData || snapshot.data.isEmpty) return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(valueColor: new AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.red),));
    else {
      return createNewTaskView(context, snapshot.data);
    }
```

If the future does not have data (snapshot.hasData = false) and you use the ! operator, createNewTaskView will be called with null list and this is the error that you are getting.

You can try replacing with something like :

```
if (!snapshot.hasError && snapshot.hasData) {
    return createNewTaskView(context, snapshot.data);
} else {
  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(valueColor: new AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.red),));
}
```